# react arrow function map into map (map is not a function)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
{order &&
  order.map((item, i) =>
   <tr key={i}>
    {item.attributes.map((itemAttr) => itemAttr)}
   </tr>
  )
}
```

I'm trying to build a table using the same Object, first map builds TR second map buids TD but I can't make it work, it gives me 'item.attributes.map is not a function'

Comment: Could you please add the data you are using without that it is impossible to answer this question?

Comment: Should return JSX, `{item.attributes.map((itemAttr) => itemAttr)}` are you sure `itemAttr` return a valid one?

Comment: You can use map function on array, if `item.attributes` is not an array, you will get error 'item.attributes.map is not a function'

Comment: clearly order is not an array

Comment: order Object, sorry for that!
https://i.imgur.com/YEt3A10.png

Comment: The first map works fine, if I just want to print lest say 'item.attributes'.
The second map is what makes it go 'not a function'

Comment: attributes is also an object .  . map is an array method . Hence the error .

Comment: the error screenshot, maybe it helps idk https://i.imgur.com/YCX4pJB.png

Comment: If you are only interested in the values like 31, 1.00, teste2 then you can use Object.values(item.attributes).map() ;

Answer (score 1):

Problem was attributes was an object as Mr. [Harmandeep Singh Kalsi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7118342/harmandeep-singh-kalsi)
 noticed. Thank you!

Resolved code:

```
{order &&
            order.map((item, i) =>
              <tr key={i}>
                <td>
                  {item.attributes['title']}
                </td>
                <td>
                  {item.attributes['quantity']}
                </td>
                <td>
                  {item.attributes['total_price']['formatted']}
                </td>
              </tr>
            )
          }
```